# How can i access data from series in tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am using highcharts network graph and i wanted to access value field present inside data to display it on hovering over the node. I am unable to access that using this.point.value.can anyone please help me in clearing this issue?

This is my code:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function () {
    return '<b>' + 'Tree' + '</b><br>' +
      'Name: ' + this.point.name + '<br>' +
      'Description: ' + this.point.value;
  }
},

series: [{
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: true
  },
  data: [
    {
      from: 'location',
      to: 'addr',
      value: 'This is sample data'
    }
  ]
}]
```

Comment: What chart type are you trying to use ?

Comment: If you console.log `this` in your tooltip, you'll be able to drill down through what's available and find `series`. Offhand I think you can get to it via `this.point.series` and find your node from there

Answer (score 0):

You can access it using `this.point.linksFrom[0].value`. Check code and demo posted below.

**Code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'networkgraph'
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      var text = '<b>' + 'Tree' + '</b><br>' +
        'Name: ' + this.point.name + '<br>';

      if (this.point.linksFrom[0]) {
        text += 'Description: ' + this.point.linksFrom[0].value;
      }

      return text;
    }
  },
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true
    },
    data: [{
      from: 'location',
      to: 'addr',
      value: 'This is sample data'
    }, {
      from: 'point2',
      to: 'addr',
      value: 'Another data'
    }]
  }]
});
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/cohnks96/1/